# Setting certain item in select option from object collection using ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

#### Short description of the problem:

I am facing 2 problems while using "select" in ionic which is working properly when i tried only using angularjs. 
1. Initially i am setting array of 1st index to select which is coming blank.
2. I am trying to update array by splicing and trying to update select which is again bringing me blank select option.

#### What behavior are you expecting?

2 problems i am expecting respective array item to be selected which is given through controller.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. At start when u run the app we get blank select option.
2. The other problem can be seen by deleting any item and other default item to be selected.

#### Code Snippet:

```
            .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.options = [{name: 'var1',id: 1}, { name: 'var2', id: 2}, {name: 'var3',id: 3}];
            $scope.yourSelect = $scope.options[0];

            $scope.delete = function() {
              //  alert("Clciked");
              $scope.Deleted = $scope.options.splice(1,1);
              $scope.yourSelect = $scope.options[0];
                alert( $scope.yourSelect.name);
            }

            $scope.changed = function(yourSelect) {
                alert( $scope.yourSelect.name);
              }
            })
```

#### For Ionic 1 issues:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZriDlmQL8VPRdk1NnDNa?p=preview

#### ionic info :

Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for you - http://plnkr.co/edit/qODVOqnhsdTR7lAgLBvv?p=preview

RE: At start when u run the app we get blank select option.
That is because of the ng-init not been set correctly. Instead of

```
ng-init="yourSelect='var1'"
```

You should have just:

```
ng-init="yourSelect"
```

The reason why is that the selected option should be an object, one of those, declared with ng-options, and not a string value. When you select an option, Angular will give you a reference to the selected object, not to the selected "value".

RE: The other problem can be seen by deleting any item and other default item to be selected.
Check in the controller.js file how we update the model in $scope.changed() and then how the selected for deletion option is removed from the $scope.options array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @toxic.digital . But my 1st problem was solved and deleting is still having problem not setting to default option as in following updated plunker console: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZriDlmQL8VPRdk1NnDNa?p=preview). Let me know if am missing something in this code.

Comment: Please help me out with some suggestions.Thanks in advance